# Windows 10 blank screen after resuming from hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, hibernate, asus-laptop

When I resume my laptop from hibernate, it just shows a blank screen. The screen itself is on, but the image is black and nothing is responding (The caps lock on the keyboard doesn't light up, for example).

I've tried the following:

- Checking event viewer (nothing there)
- Updating display driver (Using the latest ASUS' Intel HD drivers)
- Running an sfc /scannow
- Booting into diagnostic mode
- Turning on/off fast startup

My laptop: ASUS Vivobook X512FA

Any way I can fix this issue?

EDIT: For some reason cycling whether hibernate is enabled doesn't work anymore. No idea what I did before, but at some point after messing around with the hibernate and fast startup it worked once or twice)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the BIOS fixed it. For reference, my laptop is the ASUS X512FA, and I was running BIOS version 300. I update to 301 using the EZ utility in the BIOS, and now it resumes from hibernate like a charm.